# Does every table really need a PK?

Tags: database-design

I was creating a data structure and one of the tables does not have any definate uniquness.

It is a table to hold payment entries (so two entries could be the same)

It will be linked but on a one to many basis. i.e. Returning all lines where account number = x

It will be used for display, no updates or deletes only inserts.

I stopped to consider if this table needed a primary key and my college was adamant that every table should have a primary key no matter what. So he added an incrementing id (using a sequence).

To me this means
   There is a sequence that is using resources and not really contributing anything.
   An index is created on the table that will never be used but will have an overhead.
   If I ever needed to delete one specific line in an emergency I could use the built-in rowid.

I know tables should have a PK but does EVERY table really need one? Am I missing something?
thank you for your time.

Comment: It depends on how strict you want to be about sticking to relational theory.

Comment: @PaulG - Ever hear about [Cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)?

Comment: Why would you want to have duplicate data in a table? A database is a collection of propositions (facts). Stating the same fact twice doesn't make that fact any more true. Duplication only leads to ambiguity, inaccuracy and makes operations on the data more complex and prone to error.

Answer (score 3):

Your table almost certainly needs a primary key. And an ID number isn't the answer.

A primary key *or* its equivalent. (A `NOT NULL UNIQUE` constraint, for example.)

If you can't distinguish one thing from another without an id number, then you can't distinguish one thing from another *with* an id number.

Without a key, a table of payment entries might end up looking like this.

```
account_id  payment_type  payment_amount
--
10167       cash          $10.00
10167       cash          $10.00
10167       cash          $10.00
10167       cash          $10.00
```

Common queries about payments might include

- How many payments have been made against account 10167?
- How much has been paid against account 10167?

You might be tempted to answer "4", and $40.00. But two of those entries are duplicates. (Programming error, probably. Some days I'm challenged by "Hello, world." You can't expect me to get this complex stuff right all the time.)

If you altered my original table to take an id number, you'd end up with this.

```
id    account_id  payment_type  payment_amount
--
1     10167       cash          $10.00
2     10167       cash          $10.00
3     10167       cash          $10.00
4     10167       cash          $10.00
```

And you still can't tell there are two duplicate entries.

Comment: In summary .. adding a surrogate PK doesn't fix a bad design :p However, it's not true: "If you can't distinguish one row from another without an id number, then you can't distinguish one row from another with an id number." By definition *all* PKs are Candidate Keys and can thus "unique identify a record" (as much as any Candidate Key) and can be used as an FK-target. However, surrogate PKs still might not correctly cover the problem/model, as shown in the example.

Comment: @pst: Right. *Surrogate* essentially means "substitutes for, or takes the place of"--a surrogate mother takes the place of a natural mother for childbirth. A surrogate key, strictly speaking, must take the place of a natural key. No natural key, no surrogate key. Just one more meaningless integer.

Comment: A Surrogate Key can still be a Candidate Key. In the case of an auto-incremenet it adds an "identity" to a column (it is a CK because the value is unique per RS), but not necessarily the appropriate semantic information .. I agree that a surrogate auto-PK won't fix a bad design.

Comment: @pst: There's a difference between identifying a row and identifying the thing the row represents. Identifying a row is trivial (and it's SQL, not relational); identifying the thing the row represents can be a problem.

Comment: I agree with this conclusion .. just not some specific wording. I would give another +1 if I could, however.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer a more philosophical point of view...

A table is just a physical representation of a relation. And any given tuple can exists in a relation at most once (relation is a set, and an element can either belong or not belong to a set; it cannot belong multiple times).

By not having a key, and consequently not being able to distinguish between individual rows, you are potentially having multiple physical rows representing the same logical tuple. You are not adding any useful information to the system, you are just wasting space.

---

In your particular situation, the logical meaning of a key-less table...

```
account   amount
123       $10.00
```

...is exactly the same as (for example)...

```
account   amount
123       $10.00
123       $10.00
123       $10.00
123       $10.00
```

If you actually **want** to know that `$10.00` was paid to account `123` 4 times, why not just have...

```
account   amount    count
123       $10.00    4
```

...and make the `{account, amount}` a key? Theoretically, you can always transform a key-less table into a keyed table by putting the existing columns in a key and adding a count.

But in practice, you probably don't care much about how many times any *particular* amount was paid - you care about order and/or time of payments (and about having a correct sum at the end). So why not base a key on that?

Comment: I don't agree with the "logical meaning" here .. but I like the bit at the end that talks about adding different (desired) information.

Comment: @pst There is a difference between the mathematical concept of relation and the physical concept of table. If you view the above as a relation, they are the same. If you view it just as a table, then they are different, but then we are no longer within the realm of the relational model...

Comment: Ah yes. It doesn't seem very clear [to me] in the post though :(

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice, yes. It's part of normalizing data, yes.

But sometimes you must denormalize in order to store data properly and let upper layers read it as it is. So the answer is NO, it's not a silver bullet.

Just try to use indexes to enhance queries and design your DBs properly (identifying the right PK/FK if available), normalizing in an adequate way that holds the controls and needs of your app.